# iptables forward port from ext network to the int

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I have 2 ip addresses on iface eth0:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:99:a4:14:08  
          inet addr:85.25.152.115  Bcast:85.25.152.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::219:99ff:fea4:1408/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:233866 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:145186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:175800889 (167.6 MiB)  TX bytes:38033903 (36.2 MiB)
          Interrupt:18 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:99:a4:14:08  
          inet addr:85.25.248.216  Bcast:85.25.248.255  Mask:255.255.255.192
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:18
```

and I have an internal virtual iface for virtualbox guest:

```
tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ae:ba:ce:d7:7d:bd  
          inet addr:10.0.1.1  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::acba:ceff:fed7:7dbd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:111 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

10.0.1.1 is GW for the VM (10.0.1.2). The forwarding from 10.0.1.2 to the internet works perfectly, but when I'm trying to redirect all the ports from 85.25.248.216 (eth0:1) to the 10.0.1.2 it fails:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 85.25.248.216 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.2
nmap -A -v 85.25.248.216
<...>
PORT      STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp    open  ssh     OpenSSH 5.8p1 Debian 4 (protocol 2.0)
| ssh-hostkey: 1024 4e:3e:ce:86:24:f8:54:7a:68:67:be:57:92:62:00:f0 (DSA)
|_2048 36:f5:0d:4c:1b:58:b8:f9:ff:0f:47:ba:88:43:69:bd (RSA)
10000/tcp open  http    MiniServ 1.540 (Webmin httpd)
|_html-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html).
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 2.6.X
OS details: Linux 2.6.19 - 2.6.31

india827:~# iptables --list -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       all  --  anywhere             static-ip-85-25-248-216.inaddr.intergenia.de to:10.0.1.2 
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             static-ip-85-25-248-216.inaddr.intergenia.de tcp dpt:3389 to:10.0.1.2 

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       all  --  anywhere             static-ip-85-25-248-216.inaddr.intergenia.de to:10.0.1.2 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
SNAT       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            to:85.25.248.216
```

The VM is on Windows, and there must be, at least, 3389 (RDP) opened, but I (of course!) cant connect to it too. Where is the mistake?

**New rules:**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 85.25.248.216 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.2
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -d 10.0.1.2 -j ACCEPT
```

Result is the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iptables command is correct so it must be something in the context. I'll try guessing.

**IP forwarding is not enabled.**

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

should give a value of **1**. If not then set it to **1** by

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

**You are SNATing 10.0.1.2 to 85.25.152.115 on its way out**

```
iptables --list -t nat
```

should reveal that.

Comment: Ip forwarding is enabled.

Comment: iptables --list -t nat is in the first post

Comment: First I'd remove that **SNAT** to the same outside IP. This basically tells netfilter to do a PAT on all outgoing traffic, so all ports get re-assigned on their way out. I'm not sure it will take precedence over the **DNAT** returning traffic but it might. If you don't want to completely disable the rule you can add an exception for the specific IP like this **iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.1.2 -j ACCEPT

Comment: So, what is the correct solution for my problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing the **SNAT** rule?

Comment: Yes, I cleared all the iptables rules & added the following:

Comment: As the last lines in 1st post.

Comment: Are you able to connect to TCP/3389 (or any other port) from the Linux box? You can also run a capture with _tcpdump_ to see if traffic is indeed being forwarded.

Comment: Oh no... The problem was appear because RDP service was not enabled on the Win server... Thank you! Btw, the nmap from linux boxs' localhost to 85.25.248.216 still shows SSH & Webmin ports :)

Comment: Well you can limit SSH (and Webmin I think) to only listen to a specific IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the Virtualbox NAT forwarding?

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward

Then just adjust iptables to open the host ports. You're already running a NAT router in Virtualbox, why run two?

Comment: Forwarding host ports < 1024 impossible: On Unix-based hosts (e.g. Linux, Solaris, Mac OS X) it is not possible to bind to ports below 1024 from applications that are not run by root.